# Could I use 2 step verification on my BlueStacks?

Tags: bluestacks, 2-step-verification

When I was checking my google account for some stuff, I noticed that google recognized my virtual BlueStacks emulator as an connected device

So I was thinking if I could use my BlueStacks to actually use 2 step verification

Comment: My guess is that it won't work as an emulator is not a valid Google Android device (and thus will not pass the Android SafetyNet check).

Comment: But google recognized it as a valid device

Comment: Google even thought it was a real device that I could install apps to it @Robert